# Breakpoint on enum creation

Tags: c#, debugging, enums

I have an enum, and I am trying to figure out what code is actually creating an instance of it. I have a whole lot of code, and I am fairly certain the code that I am looking for is in one of the many obscure projects that is not in my current solution, so find usages won't work.

I know there is no such thing as a constructor on an enum, but I would really like a way to break execution and examine the call stack anytime any code creates and uses this enum. I have tried putting breakpoints on individual enum values, but they never toggle, even when I know they are being used.

Is this possible, or am I going to need to take a different route to find what I am looking for.

Comment: Did you look at "Find all References" in the context menu?

Comment: Can you use the 'Go to Definition' menu option to find it? Or 'Find all References' to see where it is being used? Also, use the Object Browser to find it.

Comment: Yes I tried find all references. It is insufficient in this case because not all code that uses my enum is loaded into my current solution, and I can't load it all in because I don't know where the code that calls it is, and there are something like 100 other projects that it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is technically possible, assuming you control the code of the enum itself:

1. Rename YourEnum to YourEnumInternal
2. Create class YourEnum and put a Property for each value in YourEnumInternal, with the same name, and return the respective member of YourEnumInternal.
3. Put breakpoints in every property.

Also, if what you really want to do is look at the callstacks when members of this enum are added to a particular collection (as you said in a comment), why not find usages on the collection (which hopefuly has a smaller scope?) and put breakpoints (or better yet, TracePoints with the $CALLSTACK psuedovariable) wherever items are added to it?

Comment: That's a cool idea. I've already found what i am looking for, but I was mostly curious if it is technically possible to extend enums to debug them in this way. I would have to rebuild all of the existing code to use the class instead of the enum, but that isn't too bad.

Comment: @CMP, Loading and finding all references is too much but rebuilding all code it fine? I don't get it...

Comment: The code base is pretty messed up and hard to navigate. nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Find All References`, then you can set breakpoints in the appropriate places.

Comment: Find all references only works for code loaded in the current solution. This is in a core package that is referenced by a lot of code that is not in my current solution, and it is not practical to load it all.

Comment: @CMP, if that is not practical why are you considering finding all uses of the enum at all? If you are planning to change the enum you will break some (perhaps all) of that code so you will have to look into all of this code anyway.

Comment: I don't want to find all usages. That is not my intent. I wish to debug and see a stack trace when it is used in certain execution paths. I am not trying to change the enum, but deduce which code is populating a particular collection of them. It seems that is not possible, so I will need to dig deeper into the code to figure this out.

Comment: CMP - Move your mouse of a variable that is decalared as the enumeration in question.  This will expose what framework it is in.  You can use this information to figure our which project it is.  I strongly suggest you DOCUMENT going forward if you really have 100 projects linked together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Object Browser in VS to search for your enum. It includes assemblies that are referenced (but not part of your solution as projects).